# I have a Django web app that relies heavily on third-party data. How to make the two sides independent but still usable?

Tags: django, web-applications, etl, data-warehouse

I am building a web app using Django, but I have some doubts about the best architecture.

The real-life scenario is more complex, but - for the sake of keeping it simple - let's use the example of a Fantasy Football app.

There are two sides:

- the Football data (Matches, Clubs, Players, etc.) that comes from a third party API
- the Game data (Users, Fantasy leagues, Fantasy teams, etc.) that is generated inside the web app

My first thought is that the Football data should be handled outside Django, for example having my ETL/ELT pipeline in phython scripts (e.g. using Polars) orchestrated using Airflow.
In the real-life scenario there may be multiple sources, and the data could also be used for other purposes (e.g. analytics), so I think it would be best to keep it in a separate db that acts as my data warehouse. Also, this would make it so that the ETL process won't take away resources from the web app (although I guess I could achieve the same with e.g. Celery), and that I can keep my codebase separate.

Question 1: Does this make sense?

Second, I have the web app. I suppose that to use Football data that comes from the warehouse, I can simply leverage Django's multi db support, and for instance query next week's matches in the DWH to show them in the web app.
What I don't get here is how to handle data that overlaps: for example, how do I assign a player (stored in the DWH) to a fantasy team (stored in the web app's db). From what I know, there is no support for cross-database relations in Django.

Question 2: How to handle cross-database relations?

Finally, there will likely be some code that could be useful on both sides. For instance, I might want to limit the countries I query from the API, and in the web app have the same countries selectable in a form.

Question 3: if I keep the codebases separate, what options do I have to use it on both sides without replicating?

Are there best practices for this type of application? What would be the best approach?

For now, my code is all in the Django project, in separate apps. But I feel like I will regret it later on.